# Why can't a column be set to null using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's start with this entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  ...
  @Column(length = 80)
  private String description;

  @Column(name = "enum_column", precision = 18)
  @Convert(converter = EnumColumnConverter.class)
  private MyEnum enumColumn;
  ...
}
```

Here, you see two columns that are nullable (in my entity and in the database). The converter replaces the enum with a `Long` value in the database. A repository class is defined accordingly:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
```

A DTO is defined from a service package:

```
public class MyEntityDto {
  ...
  private String description;
  private MyEnum enumColumn;
  ...
}
```

Mapping between DTOs and entities is done using Dozer. A DTO is modified from a Java FX UI. A service has been defined between UI and persistence to save modified entities.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyEntityService {
  @Autowired MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;

  ...

  public List<MyEntityDto> save(List<MyEntityDto> dtosToSave) {
    List<MyEntityDto> results = Collections.emptyList();

    if (dtosToSave != null && !dtosToSave.empty()) {
      Iterable<MyEntity> entities = convertDtosWithDozer(dtosToSave);
      List<MyEntity> savedEntities = myEntityRepository.saveAll(entities);
      results = convertEntitiesWithDozer(savedEntities);
    }
    return results;
}
```

From the UI, I modify an existing row where both `description`and `enumColumn` are not `null`. Both values are set to `null`.

The problem is that none of them is set to `null` in the database. In the logs, the `update` request generated by Hibernate does not include these columns. When I debug the code, these columns are `null` in `dtosToSave`, `entities`, `savedEntities` and `results`.

I created a unit test for `MyEntityRepository` where I save an entity with non null `description` and `entityColumn`. I reload the entity from the database using the repository to be sure these columns are not null. I set them to `null`, save the entity, and load it back from the database. Now both columns are indeed `null`, which is what I've been expecting.

My question: what am I missing here? Why the repository does not save `null` columns? If I set any non null values, it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: could my problem be related to this? [Jpa Repository save() doesn't update existing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065939/jpa-repository-save-doesnt-update-existing-data)

Comment: Why using this converter ? What it does ?

Comment: @CodeScale As I mentioned, the converter is used to replace the enum with a long in the database. We are currently updating a software. Minimum modifications are allowed in the database. And there is a lot of legacy code using this information. But this is not the problem...

Comment: @CodeScale I chose these two columns, but it could have been other ones.

Comment: In your repository you define Long as Pk type.. don't see the Id in your entity ?

Comment: @CodeScale Yes, there is an id. If you notice, the content of the class started and ended with "...", meaning that there are other columns and methods. I omitted them because I didn't think they were necessary to describe the problem. I wanted to show an example with columns in trouble.Is it really that confusing not seeing an id, and assuming there is one? Do you want me to add the whole entity? There are exactly 43 columns, including one ID... I can do it if you really want.

Comment: No I trust you ;-)..43.... huge...damn and during update all columns appears in the update statement excepted these two ?

Comment: @CodeScale Exactly. In my example, the only modified columns are those two. In the logged update request generated by Hibernate, only these two columns are missing. And there are no changes in the database.

Comment: Any news? Did you check m'y answer?

Comment: @CodeScale Yes, I checked your answer and accepted it. You were right. I didn't reply before because I wanted to verify this behavior on older versions of our code. Somehow, what I don't understand is that, on these older version, such problem never occured. We were able to update null columns. I'll have to do more reading about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You convert your dtos to entities via dozer but as this point entities are still in detached-state.... to update existing entities you first need to load them through database via your repository. Something like `repository.findById(Id id);`

Then you will get entity in "attached" state and so state transitions(update on fields) will be applied.

During the `save()` all your entity state transitions will be translated to corresponding DML and your update should work now.

And regarding this statement

```
 I reload the entity from the database using the repository to be sure these columns are not null. I set them to null, save the entity, and load it back from the database. Now both columns are indeed null, which is what I've been expecting.
```

As you said `you reload entity from the database` so it works