# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint, but it shouldn't [Spring Boot, PostgreSQL]

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, model-view-controller

**A short description of the code:**

User can create a category. Other users then can see that and other categories. They can then press 'follow' on a category and then they are saved to a database. There is picture bellow which shows how it looks in the DB. Everything works fine up to this point.

User can create many categories and category can have one owner only.

Categories can have many followers, User can follow many categories.

**The problem**

However, when user then presses 'follow' on another category (with different category ID and all (see HTML and browser screenshot below)) my program crashes and I get this error (excerpt):

```
2020-10-09 20:12:21.526  WARN 25512 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2020-10-09 20:12:21.526 ERROR 25512 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "followed_categories_pkey"
  Detail: Key (user_id, category_id)=(37, 5) already exists.
2020-10-09 20:12:21.526  INFO 25512 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2020-10-09 20:12:21.529 ERROR 25512 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [followed_categories_pkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "followed_categories_pkey"
  Detail: Key (user_id, category_id)=(37, 5) already exists.
```

And also indicates that it crashes at:

(this points to a `userService.updateUser(user);` in the controller)

```
at com.blog.reviewwebsite.controller.CategoryController.followCategory(CategoryController.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
```

**despite both debugger and html showing that I am passing user_id = 37, category_id = 6.**

**However**, if I stop my IDE and start it again (DB still shows first follow, like in the picture) and then I sign in with the same user (same user_id) and press follow on another category, everything works and database gets updated (see picture below).

Then, if I try to follow yet another category, same crash happens again, I would have to restart IDE for it to work again.

**Goal**

User should be able to follow multiple categories without crashes

**What I have tried** (nothing helped):

I've tried adding `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` in the User class.

Overriding Equals and Hashcode in both entity classes.

**Entities**

- User

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    //other fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    //This one is used when a user makes a new category
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Category> categories;


    //This one is used when a user follows existing category
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "followedCategories",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    )
    private Set<Category> followedCategories = new HashSet<Category>();
}
```

- Category

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "Category")
public class Category {

    //other fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long id;

    //This one is used when a user makes a new category
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    //This one is used when a user follows existing category
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followedCategories")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryController {

    private CategoryService categoryService;
    private UserService userService;

    public CategoryController(CategoryService categoryService, UserService userService) {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    //other methods

    @PostMapping("/follow/{id}")
    public String followCategory(@PathVariable Long id, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
        Category category = categoryService.getOneById(id);
        user.getFollowedCategories().add(category);
        userService.updateUser(user);

        return "redirect:/categories/all";
    }
}
```

***Service***

- UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    //other methods

 public User updateUser(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

- Category Service

```
@Service
public class CategoryService {

    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public CategoryService(CategoryRepository categoryRepository) {
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }

    //other methods

    public Category getOneById(Long id) {
        return categoryRepository.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

**Repository**

- User Repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findUserByUsername(String username);
}
```

- Category Repository

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
}
```

**Relevant HTML code (with thymeleaf)**

```
<div th:each="category: ${categories}">


    <p> Category:
        <span><a th:href="@{/reviews/(categoryId=${category.id})}" th:text="${category.name}"></a>
        <span th:text="${category.user.username}"></span>
        <span th:text="${category.id}"></span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/categories/follow/{id}/(id=${category.id})}">
        <span>follow</span>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</div>
```

How it looks in the browser:

[image: categories with who created it and category id]

How DB looks after following once

[image]

How DB looks after following once, restarting IDE, and then following another category

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited) SOLVED:

found actual answer and solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59067006/12826439

needed not to pass user from controller, but to get user by its id from repository.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably that you didn't implement equals/hashCode for `Category` so adding it to the set will add a duplicate which is then tried to be persisted.