# Spring Batch/Data JPA application not persisting data to db

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I'm having really weird issue. I need to say that my code working perfectly fine in my local but not persisting some datas in our pod (k8 environment).

I have different datasources to work with in this batch. Everything running fine. Job Repository is map-based and using ResourcelessTransactionManager for it. I configured it like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){


    }
}
```

I also use different platformtransactionmanager then spring batch ([issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/816)). So I set my spring allow bean overriding to true in my properties. The platform transaction manager in my configurer is right binded one, I debugged it.

I have custom writer for one of my step. Updating records in multiple tables which in multiple dbs (different datasources, in brief)

```
public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<MyDTO> {

    @Autowired
    private MyFirstRepo myfirstRepo; //table in first datasource

    @Autowired
    private MySecondRepo mySecondRepo; //table in second datasource
    
    
        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends MyDTO> myDtoList) throws Exception {
         //some logic
         mySecondRepo.delete(deletableEntity)

         //some logic
         mySecondRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities)

         //some logic
         myfirstRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities)
        }
    
    }
```

Since I have multiple datasources, I defined multiple transaction managers, and to give transaction manager to my step I defined chained transaction manager that includes that managers.

```
    @Bean
    public Step myStep(@Qualifier("chainedTransactionManager") ChainedTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager) {
 
        return getCommonStepBuilder("myStep")
                .transactionManager(chainedTransactionManager)
                .<MyDTO,MyDTO>chunk(200)
                .reader(myPaginingReader())
                .writer(myWriter())
                .taskExecutor(myTaskExecutor())
                .throttleLimit(15)
                .build();

    }
```

chained transaction manager config (both of these transaction manager is JpaTransactionManager):

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionManagerConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "chainedTransactionManager")
    public ChainedTransactionManager transactionManager(

            @Qualifier("firstTransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager firstTransactionManager,

            @Qualifier("secondTransactionManager")PlatformTransactionManager secondTransactionManager) {

        return new ChainedTransactionManager(firstTransactionManager,secondTransactionManager);

    }

}
```

So my first two jpa operations in writer working just fine( operations that made over `MySecondRepo`) but the last operation is not persisting data to db. It doesn't throws any errors, job completing succesfully but it doesn't update my records in table.

I must mention second time, it does update in my local actually. Just not updating in our app that lives on k8 environment (dockerized microservice). Which is making it so confusing. Any idea why is it happening?

Edit: I created another writer bean for myfirstRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities) (as jdbc batch item writer, executing same logic) and add two of these writer to composite one. Now it's working as expected. But I have a lot of concerns now since I don't know what caused it. Any idea?

Edit 2: I came across with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065939/jpa-repository-save-doesnt-update-existing-data). I was using `JdbcPagingItemReader`, does entities fetched with this component are in `managed` state? Entites inside `mySecondRepo.delete(deletableEntity)` and
`mySecondRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities)` are fetched inside writer by using hibernate but `myfirstRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities)` entities are the ones that came from reader.
It all makes sense if it is the case but even it is then why it was working fine in local?

Answer (score 0):

> mySecondRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities) are fetched inside writer by using hibernate but myfirstRepo.saveAll(updatableEntities) entities are the ones that came from reader.

Fetching items in the item writer is the cause of your issue. This is incorrect, it is not expected to read items in the item writer. That's why items coming from the reader are saved, but not the ones fetched in the writer.

What you should know is that all writers in the composite are running in the scope of a single transaction, driven by the transaction manager of the step. So if you are writing data to multiple datasources, you need to make sure the transaction manager is coordinating the transaction between all datasources. `ChainedTransactionManager` is deprecated, you can use a `JtaTransactionManager` for your case.

Comment: Actually things happen reverse of you say. Items coming from the reader are not saved, the ones saved are the ones I fetched in writer. I misspelled that part, corrected post now. I need to ask why fetching items in writer is wrong? You got me worried by saying that. I did not encounter any abnormal situation until now.

Comment: I should ask the question like this:  What are the risks of reading in writer? What situations can I encounter? Did you say that because it is not best practice to do or could it cause any error?

Comment: It does not make sense to read data in the item writer. An `ItemWriter` is designed to write items that were read by an `ItemReader`. Everything is possible technically, but not because you can do it that you should do it. A side case is enriching items read by the reading with an item processor (like in the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders)). Other than that, things start to become more like an anti-pattern than a pattern.